# Looking for better way to run elixir code

Tags: elixir, httpoison

New to elixir and I only have found 2 ways to run code. Wondering if there's a better way:

1. open interactive shell and run one or multiple functions inside a module by calling `Module_name.function_name()` which just runs that function
2. If I want to run the entire module then I open interactive shell and have to paste all the code from the module into the shell then hit `enter`

I'm sure it's obvious but I can't find any satisfactory answers anywhere. Just tried option #2 with this module and it returned this when it should return a list of reviews. Thanks.

```
defmodule KgbScrape do
  use HTTPoison.Base
  @endpoint "https://www.dealerrater.com/dealer/McKaig-Chevrolet-Buick-A-Dealer-For-The-People-dealer-reviews-23685/page"

  def build_urls() do
    page_num = ["1","2","3","4","5"]
    tail_url = ["/?filter=#link"]
    for page <- page_num, tail <- tail_url do
      urls_list = @endpoint <> page <> tail
    end
  end
  def fetch_pages(url) do
    url
    |> HTTPoison.get()
    |> response()
  end

  def process_pages(urls_list) when is_list(urls_list) do
    resp =
      urls_list
      |> Task.async_stream(fn url -> fetch_pages(url) end)
      |> Enum.map(fn {_, resp} -> resp end)

    Enum.map(resp, fn r ->
      r
      |> Floki.parse_document!()
      |> Floki.find(".review-entry")
      |> Map.new(fn entry ->
        [{"div", _, [date]}] = Floki.find(entry, "div.italic")
        [{"p", _, [content]}]  = Floki.find(entry, "p.review-content")
        {date, content}
      end)
    end)
  end

  def response({:ok, %{body: {:ok, %{"error" => error}}}}) do
    {:error, error}
  end
  def response({:ok, %{body: body}}), do: body
  def response({:error, error}), do: {:error, error}
end
```

and result is:

```
warning: redefining module KgbScrape (current version loaded from _build/dev/lib/kgbScrapeApp/ebin/Elixir.KgbScrape.beam)
  iex:7

warning: variable "urls_list" is unused (if the variable is not meant to be used, prefix it with an underscore)
  iex:15: KgbScrape.build_urls/0

{:module, KgbScrape,
 <<70, 79, 82, 49, 0, 0, 68, 252, 66, 69, 65, 77, 65, 116, 85, 56, 0, 0,
   5, 107, 0, 0, 0, 103, 16, 69, 108, 105, 120, 105, 114, 46, 75, 103,
   98, 83, 99, 114, 97, 112, 101, 8, 95, 95, 105, 110, 102, ...>>,
 {:response, 1}}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Create a [`mix` project](https://elixir-lang.org/getting-started/mix-otp/introduction-to-mix.html) and use `iex -S mix` as described in the documentation to load all the modules in the project.

The outcome you see is the result of module compilation. To use the module one must explicitly call a function, like `KgbScrape.process_pages(["url1", "url2, ...])`.

Also, one might create an `escript` with [`mix escript.build`](https://hexdocs.pm/mix/Mix.Tasks.Escript.Build.html#content) and run the resulting executable.

Comment: Thank you! I was wondering if there was another way but it sounds like using mix is the standard way to run elixir code.

Answer (score 1):

I've never used Elixir, but according to the [getting started documentation](https://elixir-lang.org/getting-started/introduction.html#running-scripts), you can use the `elixir` command:

> After getting familiar with the basics of the language you may want to try writing simple programs. This can be accomplished by putting the following Elixir code into a file:
>
> ```
> IO.puts("Hello world from Elixir")
> ```
>
> Save it as simple.exs and execute it with elixir:
>
> ```
> $ elixir simple.exs
> Hello world from Elixir
> ```